# Error connecting to Postgres database running on Docker: "dial tcp: [...] no such host"

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, tcp, localhost

Problem

$ go run cmd/syndicate/main.go
2021/01/25 16:37:25 error connecting to database: dial tcp: lookup db: no such host

Unable to connect to database when attempting to run:

```
$ go run cmd/syndicate/main.go
2021/01/25 16:37:25 error connecting to database: dial tcp: lookup db: no such host
```

&

```
$ migrate -source file://migrations -database postgres://postgres:secret@db:5432/syndicate?sslmode=disable up
error: dial tcp: lookup db on [2001:558:feed::1]:53: no such host
```

What do these two commands have in common?... Database URL. I am nearly certain my database URL is incorrect.

I have verified my postgres container is running:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                    NAMES
4e578bf646c7   adminer    "entrypoint.sh docke…"   3 days ago   Up 3 days   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   syndicate_adminer_1
729fc179aa6f   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago   Up 3 days   5432/tcp                 syndicate_db_1
```

Here's where I might be overlooking something...

```
$ docker-compose ps
       Name                      Command               State           Ports         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
syndicate_adminer_1   entrypoint.sh docker-php-e ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
syndicate_db_1        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      5432/tcp
```

#### `5432/tcp`???

I see that my adminer container is clearly mapped to my local port (`0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`), however my postgres container is only showing `5432/tcp` (and not `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp`)

- I am new to docker.. Can anyone explain why my postgres port isn't associated with my local port?
- Am I on the right track?

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: $POSTGRES_DB
      POSTGRES_USER: $POSTGRES_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD

  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate
    volumes:
      - ./migrations:/migrations
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: -source=file://migrations -database postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@db:5432/$POSTGRES_DB?sslmode=disable up

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

- PS. I tried adding `port: "5432:5432"` variable for `db` servicd

[Browse my repository at this time in history](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/tree/0b95ba633f5aa84492633b916c603a2697af94fa)

Thank you!
Connor

Answer (score 2):

add to db service

```
ports: 
   - "5432:5432"
```

Answer (score 1):

migrate -path D:/works/go/go-fiber-api-server/backend/platform/migrations -database "postgres://postgres:password@cgapp-postgres:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" up
error: dial tcp: lookup cgapp-postgres: no such host

Then I have fixed this issue to change db-host name(cgapp-postgres) into "IP ADDRESS" or host.docker.internal.

migrate -path D:/works/go/go-fiber-api-server/backend/platform/migrations -database "postgres://postgres:password@100.100.100.100:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" up
1/u create_init_tables (20.0987ms)

migrate -path D:/works/go/go-fiber-api-server/backend/platform/migrations -database "postgres://postgres:password@host.docker.internal:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" up
1/u create_init_tables (20.0987ms)

"host.docker.internal" works.